# Generated zip file with Asp.NET Core gives error Unexpected end of archive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, zip

I am trying to generate zip file from files stored as byte arrays in SQL Database. I am using this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(int id)
{
    var files = this.assignmentsService.GetFilesForAssignment(id).ToList();

    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var zipFile = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipFile.Open());
        streamWriter.Write(file.Content);
    }

    return this.File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Description.zip");
}
```

When I run it, the file is downloaded successfully and all the files are in the archive. But when I try to open one of them, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\User\Downloads\Description.zip: Unexpected end of archive

Comment: Try to `Dispose` archive manually before returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.dispose?view=net-6.0) the `ZipArchive` to ensure that it completes writing to the target stream. You can do that by wrapping the `ZipArchive` in a using block instead of using the using declaration here:

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var zipFile = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipFile.Open());
        streamWriter.Write(file.Content);
    }
}

return this.File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Description.zip");
```

Note that there is also on overload of the `File` method that [directly takes a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_). That way, you can use the using declaration for the ZipArchive while just keeping the memory stream open (the `File()` call will eventually dispose the stream after it has been written to the HTTP response):

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var zipFile = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(zipFile.Open());
    streamWriter.Write(file.Content);
}

return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", "Description.zip");
```

Comment: The first option worked for me but now there is another problem. When I open a text file it is written: System.Byte[] instead of the content of the file. And I can't open other than text file. Why may this happen?

Comment: @GeorgiKolev [`StreamWriter.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=net-6.0) writes *strings* to the stream. But it seems that the original content was supposed to be a byte array (`byte[]`). Check inside your `GetFilesForAssignment` where the `file.Content` comes from. It’s likely that there is a `.ToString()` call on a byte array.

Comment: I changed `streamWriter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file.Content));` and it works perfectly with text files but I still can't open other than text files. For example, when I try to open .docx document, it says: We're sorry. We can't open Document.docx because we found a problem with its contents.

Comment: @GeorgiKolev I would suggest you to change `file.Content` to be a byte array (you can then just write to the stream returned by `zipFile.Open()` directly, without a StreamWriter). Otherwise, binary files like your docx won’t be able to be properly written if you are using `Encoding.UTF8`.